# Why is stack still empty even when I pushed an element into it

Tags: java, stack

I'm trying to do a balancing string test. It's very annoying that even I pushed an element into the stack: stack.push(s.charAt(0)), it still says EmptyStackException at Stack.StackTest.main(StackTest.java:18).  Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class StackTest
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        //Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
        int i;
        String s = "{}(){}{}{}";
        stack.push(s.charAt(0));
        
        for (i = 1;i < s.length();i++)
        {
            if (stack.peek() == '{' && s.charAt(i) == '}')
            {
                if (!stack.empty())
                {
                    stack.pop();
                }
            }
            else if (stack.peek() == '[' && s.charAt(i) == ']')
            {
                if (!stack.empty())
                {
                    stack.pop();
                }
            }
            else if (stack.peek() == '(' && s.charAt(i) == ')')
            {
                if (!stack.empty())
                {
                    stack.pop();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                stack.push(s.charAt(i));
            }
        }
        
        while (!stack.empty())
        {
            System.out.print(stack.pop());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, on you first loop, the `} else if (stack.peek() == '[' && s.charAt(i) == ']') {` is been triggered and your popping the only element in the stack, so now it's empty

Answer (score 2):

Your stack is not empty at the first iteration of the loop, but that first iteration pops the only element from the stack. Then, when in the next iteration you call `stack.peek()`, you get the `EmptyStackException`.

You should put the `!stack.empty()` condition prior to the `stack.peek()` statement in order to avoid the `EmptyStackException`.

For example, change

```
        if (stack.peek() == '{' && s.charAt(i) == '}')
        {
            if (!stack.empty())
            {
                stack.pop();
            }
        }
```

to

```
        if (!stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek() == '{' && s.charAt(i) == '}')
        {
            stack.pop();
        }
```

You should change your other conditions the same way.